# Xpages could develop App on IOS or Android?

Tags: lotus-domino

Does Domino Designer could develop App on IOS or Android? I want to deveop approval workflow with Lotus Domino Designer, and could be installed on iPhone or Android mobilephone. I don't know whether could realize??

Comment: Your question is too broad, and should probably closed.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "can I write (on my own) a (native) mobile application and connect to Domino" then the response is **yes** you will probably use ajax and not Xpages.

If your question is "can I open on my mobile device a Xpage that I wrote on Domino" then the response is **yes**, but strictly it won't be a mobile app but a mobile web site.

If your question is "can I use my HTML5 web site on Domino to make an hybride application" (many tools can help for this like ionic or other frameset) then the response is **yes**.

If your question is "is it simple, can I build without special knowledge of the mobile Andoid IOS world an application base on my knowledge of Xpages" the response is **really no**!